# slideToggle on ul inside a nav with id does not work

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I've been banging my head over this one.

I need someone explaining me how is that this works.

So have this menu:

```
<nav id="main" class="cf">
    <div id="logo">
        <h2>Name</h2>
        <div id="ham">III</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="cf">
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/migueljosuevelazquez/ccsfgvL1/2/).**

On the CSS if the width of the viewport goes lower then 760px the `<ul>` inside the `<nav>` goes to `display: none;`

With jQuery I try to `slideToggle` the menu and then I add a class `.nav-expanded` that makes it `display: block;` and then removes the `inline` style. Like this:

```
$('#ham').click(function(){
    $('#main ul').slideToggle(400,function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display','');
    }); 
});
```

I do this so if I resize then the window the `<ul>` items are not hidden.
The problem with this is that if I toggle the menu it shows and hides right away.
Seems like the `display: none;` of the media query is the priority.

But, I do this cause I've done it before and this does not happen if I don't have an `id` for the `<nav>` tag.

**Why?**

**Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/migueljosuevelazquez/ys9kce3k/1/) for the exact same menu, but without an `id` for the `<nav>` tag.**

**As you can see in this way it works.** Someone that may share some knowledge on this? Thanks!

Comment: hmm this is interesting. I also wanna know what's going on here.

Comment: I tried and tried.... this is why i recommend using bootstrap to handle mobile ready: getbootstrap.com

Comment: What if you just try `$(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded");`

Comment: @Vikram if I tried that and then I resized the window above 760px the menu items will not be visible because the last state whas `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `#main ul` it's more important than `.nav-expanded` and when you remove the css display this element inherits the `#main ul` property. 
And also, the slideToggle already makes the element `display:block`.

Comment: Ok, but if I left only the slideToggle, after collapsing the menu it will leave a `<ul style="display:none">` and then if I make the view-port wider the menu would be hidden. 

So that's why after sliding the menu I leave the `.nav-expanded` class so I can erase the `inline style` of `display:none` for when I resize the view-port it will get the `display:block` out of the CSS media query. Take a look at the second fiddle. My question is more as to Why I can't make this work with an `id` in the `<nav>` if I need more than one `<nav>` in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Don't change CSS of 2nd fiddle.

```
$('#ham').click(function(){

    $('nav#main ul').slideToggle(400,function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display','');

    });

});
```

Here is [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ccsfgvL1/8/)

Comment: Yeah, but you if click on the button to expand and then to collapse, and then make wider the viewport you'll see that there are no menu items anymore.

Comment: Did you try making wider the viewport after expanding and collapsing the menu? The navigation should still be visible after that. Like in the 2nd fiddle I posted in the question

Comment: Re-size wider the window where the html is rendered before doing anything, and you'll see the menu in a horizontal manner.Then re-size it down. And expand and collapse the menu. Now re-size the window wider again. and there will be no menu anymore.

Comment: @Miguel_Velazkez i have updated the fiddle pls check.

Comment: Yeah but I want to target the `<nav>` that is styled as the `#main` Cuz i may have more `<nav>` tags. The css of the second fiddle is not styling `#main`. So that is why it works.